# Phonegap won't make connection to external database

Tags: javascript, php, android, html, cordova

I have been trying to get connection using Phonegap to my database with an ajax request to the PHP file that connects to it. Yet the information does not show.

For the PHP file i just make a connection and create a json string which is used later.

The Javascript file script.js is as following:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
request.open('GET' , 'http://websiteurl.com/example.php/', false);
request.send(null);
console.log(request);

if(request.status == 0)
console.log(request.responseText);

var firstname;
var obj = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
console.log(obj);
firstname       = obj[0].Firstname;

document.getElementById("firstname").innerHTML = firstname;
```

This for example is working without problems on my server and displays correctly on my page. The HTML page will load the javascript file and should display the information from firstname in the database but currently shows nothing.

```
 <script src="js/script.js"> </script>

 <div id="Info">
    <p>
        <strong>Firstname:</strong>
        <span id = "firstname"></span>
  </p>
</div>
```

I have tried changing the permissions in the phonegap config.xml and androidmanifest.xml but nothing seems to work.

Comment: what error you got? can you show what you have done changing the permissions in config.xml and androidmanifest.xml?

Answer (score -1):

You need to obey [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

You most likely need to make a Cross-domain request - hope [this article](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/2010/03/12/making-cross-domain-javascript-requests-using-xmlhttprequest-or-xdomainrequest.html) may help you.

Comment: I have used the origin permissions and set it to * aswell. Like <access origin="*" subdomains="true" />. Is this correct or need something else?

Comment: @patrick: please, share the console log of request.statusText and request.status. Also, please note that synchronous requests on the main thread are deprecated. I doubt it, but there's is a slight chance your request is forced async.

Comment: When testing this on my server i just get an "ok" and "200" for statustext en status. Though i found one thing for the config.xml where if i tried to change the access origin in platforms\android\res\xml it will go back to localhost. Now there are 2 in it and if i delete one or change it, it'll go back right after the building process.

Comment: You should modify access origin in the config.xml at the root of the project (or in www depends on the version of cordova) and then when you build the project, the change is made automatically to the file platforms/android/res/config.xml. And you're right, no need to add CORS headers to the php like suggested in this answer.

Comment: But +1 for the comment about asynchronous/synchronous, you should really change your code to use asynchronous call and a callback.